# Replacing URL encoding (%20) with + in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, urlencode, html-encode

Here's what I've got so far which works fine for redirecting single keywords, but not so well if the URL contains a URL encoded space (%20).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ /?s=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

What I'd like to do is change **%20** to be **+**.

For example, suppose I have the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/jobs/?search=first%20second
```

I'd like to redirect it to the following:

```
http://www.example.com/?s=first+second
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but not so well if the URL contains a URL encoded space (%20).
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search=([^&]+) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ /?s=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
> ```

Since the `QUERY_STRING` is already URL encoded, you need to include the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive to prevent any URL encoded strings being doubly encoded. This doesn't just apply to *spaces* (ie. `%20` to `%2520`), but to many other non-alphanumeric characters as well.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ /?s=%1 [NE,L,NC,R=301]
```

Do you still need to replace `%20` with `+`? Whether *spaces* are URL encoded as `%20` or `+` in the query string shouldn't strictly matter to the receiving application. Both will be URL-decoded as a literal *space*.

NB: Only in the query string can a *space* be URL encoded as `+`. In other parts of the URL, a `+` is seen as the literal character (plus).

#### Replace `%20` with `+` in the `search` URL parameter value

If you want to replace all %-encoded spaces (ie. `%20`) with `+` (alternative encoding) in the `search` URL parameter value then you can do it like this:

Assumptions:

- Only interested in the "search" URL parameter, since you are currently discarding all other URL parameters anyway.
- There can be any number of %-encoded spaces, ie. `%20`, in the URL parameter value.

For example:

```
# Replace all "%20" in the "search" URL parameter with "+"
# eg. "/jobs?search=foo%20bar%20baz%20pop" to "/jobs?search=foo+bar+baz+pop"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(search)=([^&]*)%20([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ $0?%1=%2+%3 [N]

# Redirect "/jobs/?search=<foo>" to "/?s=<foo>"
# (Unchanged from original redirect)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ /?s=%1 [NC,NE,R=302,L]
```

The first rule repeatedly loops *internally* until all the occurrences of `%20` have been replaced with `+` in the URL parameter value. The `N` (`next`) flag causes the ruleset to start over again from the top. On Apache 2.4+ you can set an upper (safe) limit on the number of iterations, eg. `N=20`. If there is no `%20` then this rule is essentially skipped (since the condition will not match on the initial call).

The `$0` (dollar-zero) backreference in the *substitution* string captures the entire URL-path (saves repetition). The `%1` (percent-one) backreference simply holds the "search" URL parameter name (again, saves repetition) - the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*.

The `%2` and `%3` backreferences hold the values of the 2nd and 3rd captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern*, ie. the value *before* and *after* the last `%20` character sequence in the URL parameter value.

This rule needs to be near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

The second rule is the same as your original redirect directive and actually performs the redirect, changing the URL-path and `search` URL parameter to `s`.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the earlier 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by your browser. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects - to avoid caching issues - and only change to 301 when everything works as intended.

Comment: That's right `%20 or +` would not make a difference in reading query string but may be OP wants to show `+` in URL as well

Comment: @anubhava I've updated my answer to replace `%20` with `+` in the URL parameter value. `+` does look better! ;)

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite! That seems to have done the trick. Accepting this answer.

Comment: @MrWhite: very good update, sorry I can upvote only once :)